# Is there any way to make an executable file (.exe) from a Nuxt+Node project?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I have a NuxtJS project that requires a NodeJS program running behind for some functions and logic. The project structure is as follows:

```
api
assets
components
layouts
middleware
pages
plugins
server
static
store
nuxt.config.js
package.json
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports =  {
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s',
    title: 'Project',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.scss'
  ],

  plugins: [
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],

  modules: [
    'nuxt-socket-io',
    'nuxt-i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  io: {
    sockets: [
      {
        name: 'main',
        url: process.env.APP_SERVER_URL,
        default: true
      }
    ]
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  },

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' },
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.APP_SERVER_URL,
  },

  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {},
        light: {}
      }
    }
  },

  build: {
    extend(config) {}
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w server -w nuxt.config.js server",
    "build": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1611574754.9020f2a",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.12",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.18.0",
    "nuxt-socket-io": "^1.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

**server/index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const http = require('http')
const app = require('express')()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const axios = require('axios')

const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = !isProd;

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server
if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    builder.build()
} else {
    nuxt.ready()
}
app.use(nuxt.render)

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`)
});

// other logic
```

I need an exe that can be installed in other computers for running the Nodejs server and the Nuxt stuff, like I run the code by `npm run dev` or `npm run build/start` in the development computer locally.

I have tried nexe by running `nexe -i server` but not succeeded. Is there any other way for me to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). You can run node server and other stuff with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this still need me to plant the source code in each computer. I don't want to do this

Answer (score 0):

Compiling a Node.js Application into an .exe File

Two of the most commonly used packages used to compile JavaScript files into executables are:

nexe: It is a simple command-line utility that compiles your Node.js application into a single executable file. By default, it converts it into a Windows executable.

pkg: It is a Node.js package that can convert your Node.js app into several executable files for various operating systems (all at once) or of an individual operating system.

[enter link description here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/)